# What are ":ms-properties " files?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery, testdisk

Due to a failure of a partition managing software, I had to recover the files from my local hard drive with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) on a live Ubuntu drive.

Afterwards, I encountered several files named `:ms-properties`. They only occur in the parent folder of my SkyDrive location and in the SkyDrive subfolders. Additionally, for every file or folder, there exists a corresponding `:ms-properties` file.

**Note:** I can only see these files under Linux. They disappear when using Windows.

**Screenshots**

[image: :ms-properties file for the SkyDrive folder]
[image: :ms-properties file in the SkyDrive folder]

They do not have a file extension.

**System info**

- Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
- The location of the SkyDrive folder is on a NTFS-formatted partition

Does anyone know this type of file? I've found nothing while searching via Google.

I thought of [alternate data streams](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/New_Technology_File_System_%28NTFS%29#Alternate_Data_Streams), could these files be such data streams which got extracted by TestDisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of those is an [alternate data stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) (ADS), which, in general, is arbitrary extra data programs (or the OS) associates with a file in an NTFS file system. SkyDrive (now OneDrive) apparently uses an ADS called `:ms-properties` to store some sort of meta-data it uses about the file. See Brian's first comment on [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsync/what-is-this-skydrivems-propertiesdata/c3788689-c9e1-4ef3-84ca-1d467e668c79). In a data recovery scenario, it sounds like those aren't useful because you can just drop the recovered files back into OneDrive on your new environment.